# Problem with @import compass to scss file

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I need some help with setting up compass in my scss file. 

I have all folders created, and from my point of view everything is correct, but when I am trying to save my scss file i see error in console:

```
Compilation Error
Error: File "d:\Git kopia\Personal Budget planner with php\sass\compass\utilities\color\compass\utilities\color\brightness" not found
        on line 1 of sass/d:\Git kopia\Personal Budget planner with php\sass\compass\utilities\color\_contrast.scss
        from line 1 of sass/d:\Git kopia\Personal Budget planner with php\sass\compass\utilities\_color.scss
        from line 1 of sass/d:\Git kopia\Personal Budget planner with php\sass\compass\_utilities.scss
        from line 1 of sass/d:\Git kopia\Personal Budget planner with php\sass\_compass.scss
        from line 1 of sass/d:\Git kopia\Personal Budget planner with php\sass\style1.scss
>> @import "compass/utilities/color/brightness";
```

for example: 

I have in path: .../color/brightness file with name _brightness.scss? 

Do you know what can be the reason of this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the path `.../color/brightness` resolves to:

`"php\sass\compass\utilities\color\compass\utilities\color\brightness"`

Notice the duplicated **compass\utilities\color**

---

I am infering that the correct path should resolve to:

`php\sass\compass\utilities\color\brightness`

It looks like you want it to be included in `_contrast.scss` at:

`compass\utilities\color\_contrast.scss`

So from this directory, you just need to do:
`@import "./brightness"` since the `_brightness` partial is in the same directory as the `_contrast` partial.